# How to run a Java File with Jar file support in different Operating System

Tags: java

I need to run a Single  Java File ( A Unit Test java program ) on to the Linux Server .
This java File requires some third party Jar files , to run successfully.

Please let me know what is the way i can run this .java class file from Linux Server ??

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps this should be asked on superuser?

Comment: I am not as smart as you to be a super user like you .

Comment: Well , i got the answer java -cp /path/to/somefolder/*.jar com.YourMainClass

Comment: Well, I meant this site: http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

java -cp /path/to/somefolder/*.jar com.YourMainClass